# Make all events fill slot duration in Fullcalendar timeline view

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm currently developing an online resource scheduler, using the Fullcalendar Scheduler v3.9 . I'm close to finishing a prototype, the only thing missing is this last issue I've been facing for a couple of days.

In Timeline view the width of a event are relative to its duration, I however, want the duration to always fill the whole day, just like using allDay=true, regardless of the events duration. How would one this without using allDay=true on all events? [Illustration of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQQeY.png)

I've been trying to use the "eventRender:" callBack to edit the css of each rendered event however I can't figure out a good way to fill each day since the width of the event is decided by the "left" and "right" pixel position and not dependent on a day specific .

I did a really ugly fix where the min/maxTime duration was really narrow(12:00 and 12:30) it worked for most cases but if any event is outside this interval it won't be rendered on that day.

Here is a piece of my calendar settings, tell me if you need any more code:

```js
            function GenerateScheduler(schedule) {

                $('#schedulerHome').fullCalendar({
                    defaultView: 'timelineWeek',
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    views: {
                        timelineFiveDays: {
                            type: 'timelineWeek',
                            duration: { days: 5 },                     
                        },
                    minTime: '06:00:00',
                    maxTime: '18:00:00',
                    slotDuration: '12:00:00',
                    slotLabelFormat: ['[Week] w',
                    'dddd D/M'], 
                    weekends: false,
                    eventTextColor: 'white',
                    displayEventTime: true,
                    displayEventEnd: true,
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Dear ChTuri, welcome here. I just intend to suggest that Please use Version 4, its a new release with many updates. And updates will be given to this release in future. https://fullcalendar.io/blog/2019/03/v4-officially-released

Comment: Hi Khurram, thank you for your suggestion. I was planning to make the upgrade after I finish my prototype. However, since I started making the website with version 3.9 I just want to finish it with the current version to see if it is a working concept.

Comment: Actually, the calendar and scheduler methodology and other functions are bit changed in newer version(s). You might be required to alter the code again, so it would be better to learn new version and apply changes on it.

Comment: I agree with Khurram, version 3 and version 4 are [very different](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3) - it would potentially be a complete re-write, not just a simple upgrade. So if you are only just starting, you should consider using v4 from the beginning

Comment: In regards to your actual question, you seem to know about `allDay: true`, so why not just set that option on your events? It does exactly what you want. What's the reason not to use it, exactly? If you still want to display specific times on your events you could do that by modifying the title (using eventRender!). But you're missing a visual trick if you make them all look the same, since it conveys less information to the user about exactly when the event occurs. Maybe consider whether your requirement is actually a usability advantage...or not.

Comment: If you go round customising CSS and so on you'll have maintenance issues if you ever upgrade fullCalendar, plus it's quite complicated because the way the calendar is rendered means things don't fit neatly into elements within each other, instead things are overlaid on top of grids, so lots of JS and maths is used to calculate the correct positions. It's not something you can easily mangle with CSS (or at least, it's not something you can easily mangle and make it work correctly). And also if you then wanted it to work on other types of view (not timeline) you'd have to start all over again.